# How to make a Strategy in Haskell Control.Parallel.Strategies?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

**Update**: I just found [this documentation page](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/parallel/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html). Wish there was a link to it from [the documentation that I'd been using](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/libraries/base/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html), which seemed to be the definitive API doc. But maybe it's a new, unreleased work.

**Update 2**: This documentation has given me a lot better idea how to use the Control.Parallel.Strategies module. However I haven't quite solved the problem... see end of question.

I've been trying to use [parListChunk](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/libraries/base/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v%3AparListChunk) or some other parallel control features in Haskell. But I can't figure out how to use them. Warning: I'm a Haskell noob. I learned some things about functional programming with Scheme about 20 years ago (!).

Here's my non-parallelized function:

```
possibKs n r = [ (k, (hanoiRCountK n k r)) | k <- [1 .. n-1] ]
```

I want to parallelize it, something like this naive attempt:

```
possibKs n r 
    | n < parCutoff  = results
    | otherwise      = parListChunk parChunkSize results
    where results = [ (k, (hanoiRCountK n k r)) | k <- [1 .. n-1] ]
```

But that structure isn't right for parListChunk.
The docs say:

```
parListChunk :: Int -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
```

> parListChunk sequentially applies a
>   strategy to chunks (sub-sequences) of
>   a list in parallel. Useful to increase
>   grain size

Good, that's what I want. But how to use it? I haven't been able to find any examples of this. If I'm understanding the type declaration, parListChunk is a function that takes an `Int` and a `Strategy<a>` (borrowing C++ parametrized type notation to help check that I really am understanding this right), and returns a `Strategy<[a]>`. In my case I'm dealing with `Int` for `a` so parListChunk will need an `Int` argument and a `Strategy<Int>`. So what is a `Strategy` and how do I produce one? And once I have successfully used parListChunk, what do I do with the `Strategy` it spits out?

The [Strategy type is defined](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/libraries/base/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#t%3AStrategy) like this:

```
type Strategy a = a -> Done
```

(And that is **all** the documentation for Strategy.)
So a `Strategy<Int>` is a function that takes a parameter of type Int and returns Done. Apparently it causes its argument to get evaluated at a certain time or something. Where do I get one, and what kind should I use?

The following functions appear to return Strategies:

```
sPar :: a -> Strategy b
sSeq :: a -> Strategy b
r0 :: Strategy a
rwhnf :: Strategy a
```

But none of them let you determine the type parameter -- they produce a `Strategy<b>` when you give parameter `a`, or else you don't get to supply parameter `a`! What's up with that?? Beyond that, I have no idea what these mean.

I did find one example of the similar function [parList being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206489/haskell-speculative-parallel-execution) on SO:

```
return . maximum $ map optimize xs `using` parList
```

It uses this funky `using` function, which is declared:

```
using :: a -> Strategy a -> a
```

Fair enough... in my case I probably want `a` to be `[Int]`, so it takes a list of Ints and a `Strategy<[Int]>` and (does something? applies the strategy to the list? and) returns a list of Ints. So I tried to follow the parList example and changed my `otherwise` guard to:

```
| otherwise      = results `using` parListChunk parChunkSize
```

but I must admit I'm still shooting in the dark... I can't quite follow the type signatures around. So it's not too surprising that the above gives an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[(Int, Integer)]'
       against inferred type `a -> Eval a'
Probable cause: `parListChunk' is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of `using', namely
    `parListChunk parChunkSize'
In the expression: results `using` parListChunk parChunkSize
```

Can someone tell me what to use for the `Strategy a` argument to parListChunk? and how to use the `Strategy [a]` returned by parListChunk?

**New part**

Looking at [Basic Strategies](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/parallel/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#4), I think I need to use the `rseq` strategy. Probably. So I try

```
| otherwise      = results `using` (parListChunk parChunkSize rseq)
```

But GHC says rseq is "not in scope".
[These API docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/libraries/base/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v%3AsSeq) say there is no rseq in the package but sSeq seems to have replaced it. OK, so I used sSeq, but it's "not in scope" either. Even though I'm importing `Control.Parallel.Strategies`.

Any clues? Btw I used to get these messages about loading packages:

```
Loading package deepseq-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parallel-2.2.0.1 ... linking ... done.
```

So apparently that tells what version of the parallel package I have: 2.2.0.1. But I don't see information in the [API docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/libraries/base/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v%3AsSeq) about what version is described there. If I shouldn't use rseq or sSeq, what should I use? How come [Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206489/haskell-speculative-parallel-execution) was able to use parList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got the code working. I got it to compile by using `rwhnf` instead of `rseq`:

```
| otherwise      = results `using` (parListChunk parChunkSize rwhnf)
```

According to [this source code](http://darcs.haskell.org/packages/parallel/Control/Parallel/Strategies.hs), `rwhnf` was renamed to `rseq` in version 3. So I guess my version of the Parallel package is obsolete with respect to [this documentation](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/parallel/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#4). :-S

I guess that's part of the price of using "experimental" packages.

Anyway, the code compiles and runs. Whether it's doing anything useful with parallelism is another question...

Comment: Make sure you run the executable with +RTS -N to use multiple cores.  If you enable +RTS -s to show statistics, you can see how efficiently work is being spread across cores.  For finer-grained tuning, use ThreadScope (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/threadscope/).

Comment: Thanks, @John. In WinGCHi, I have "ghc --interactive -threaded" in the GHCi Startup options. I guess that's not enough? Can I even run multithreaded programs inside WinGCHi?

Comment: IIRC ghci always uses the threaded runtime (e.g. -threaded is implicit).  Just specify the runtime options you'd like in the startup options and you should be fine.  If you don't use -N, the default is to stay on one core even with the threaded runtime.